# How to get the job title value from another table in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have `lowongan` table that contains `title`, `lokasi`, and `level_pekerja`, and i have `apply_job` table that contains `company_id`, `job_title`, `job_loc`, and `job_lvl`. So when the user want to apply the job, they fill the apply form, and once the user submitted the apply form that user already fill, i want the `job_title` in the `apply_job` table is filled with the `title` value from the `lowongan` table.

The Model :

```
public function apply_data($where, $data, $table){
        $this->db->where($where);
        $this->db->insert($table, $data);
    }
```

The Controller :

```
public function store_apply($id){
        $data_lowongan['lowongan'] = $this->db->get_where('lowongan', ['id'=>$id])->result();

        $config['upload_path']      = './upload/';
        $config['allowed_types']    = 'pdf';
        $config['max_size']         = 2000;
        
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('pdf_file')){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('apply_form', $error);
        }else{
            $data_upload = $this->upload->data();

            $company_id = $this->input->post('company_id');
            $job_title  = $this->input->post('title');
            $user_name  = $this->session->userdata('name');
            $user_desc  = $this->input->post('user_desc');

            $data = array(
                'user_name'     => $user_name,
                'company_id'    => $company_id,
                'job_title'     => $job_title,
                'user_desc'     => $user_desc,
                'pdf_file'      => $data_upload['file_name']
            );

            $where = array(
                'company_id'    => $company_id,
            );

            $this->m_lowongan->apply_data($where, $data, 'apply_job');
            
            redirect('dashboard');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the `job_title` value into your `$data` array, which includes all the fields you're going to insert through `apply_data()`:

```
public function store_apply($id) {

    // This line doesn't seem to do anything
    $data_lowongan['lowongan'] = $this->db->get_where('lowongan', ['id'=>$id])->result();

    // Get the lowongan row based on the parsed id
    $lowongan = $this->db->get_where('lowongan', ['id' => $id])->row();

    // The rest of your code…

    $data = array(
        'user_name'  => $user_name,
        'company_id' => $company_id,
        'job_title'  => $lowongan->title, // Get the title from the $lowongan query
        'user_desc'  => $user_desc,
        'pdf_file'   => $data_upload['file_name']
    );

    // The rest of your code…

}
```